# QProcess signal/slot not working after Ctrl+Z and bg

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qprocess, qt-signals

I have a Qt GUI application that runs on Linux.

It is a `QApplication` that uses `QProcess` to do some work when a button is clicked.

The finished signal on the `QProcess` is connected to a slot:

```
connect(workerProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(onWorkerFinished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
```

Things work fine when I run the program normally on command line:

```
% myProgram
or run it in the background
% myProgram&
```

However, if I run it normally, then suspend it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and put it in the background, things stop working:

```
% myprogram
Ctrl+Z
bg
```

The GUI still responds. But when I click the button, it seems to start the `QProcess`, but the slot connected to the `finished()` signal never gets called.

Does suspending the application and putting it in the background somehow mess the signal/slot connection?

Comment: Your problem is, to me at least, very unclear.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to demonstrate the issue.  That being said, I've never encountered any situation where Qt signals/slots were affected by job control on the processes involved.

Comment: The background program probably gets suspended for some reason. Such as trying to read from standard input. Check the process state (learn `ps` command if it is unfamiliar to you).